# “Google cloud shell is temporarily unavailable. Try connecting in a few minutes.” error

Tags: google-cloud-shell

tried to restart the cloud shell or using admin account still get the same return.
I am still using trial credit and locate in South East Asia.

Any idea on this error ?

Comment: switch with superuser account and it's works. need to check what's wrong with my user account

Comment: Are you still getting the same issue with your user account using Cloud Shell?